# Add static dns entry

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

What's the equivalent of hosts files in windows ?

I want to add a dns entry so 'sql1' is pointing to localhost.

I tried adding sql1 127.0.0.1 to /etc/resolveconf/resolv.conf.d/base
and then sudo service resolveconf restart, but it's not working.
A ping to sql still gives me unknown host sql1.

Comment: Could be good to check askubuntu : http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost sql1
```

Comment: I was so simple ....   Thanks.